# Cannot open the connection when writing in loop

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to loop through a folder, read the file, remove the second row and then write the file in a new folder. I'm going to do more later. I just am running this as an initial step.

I input the file using:

```
files <- list.files(path="c:/users/~/Data/Test", pattern="CRG01*", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
```

Then I'm attempting to use lapply.

```
lapply(files, function(x) {
  #t <- read.table(x, header=TRUE,fill=TRUE) # load file
  # apply function


  #Manipulate the Power Factors Files
  mydata <-read.csv(x, header = T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  mydata<- mydata[,1:4]
  headers<- read.csv(x, header = F, nrows = 1, as.is = T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  headers<- headers[,1:4]
  x_in <- read.csv(x, skip=2,header = F, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  x_in<- x_in[,1:4]
  colnames(x_in)= headers


  # write to file
  write.table(x_in, "c:/Users/~/Data/Test/Output",  sep="\t",
              row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
})
```

When I run this I get the follwing error.

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :

 Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

At first I thought it was related to admin rights, but I was allowed to run as administrator as a test and got the same error. Now I'm at a loss for what the reason would be.

Thanks is advance!

Comment: It seems you have missed the file name in `write.table( x_in, "path/abc.csv")`

Comment: A common way to handle paths in loops is with `paste()` as in `write.table(x_in, file=paste0(path, filename)`

Comment: @PKumar, Ah dang, you're right. Not to keep asking questions, but do you know how I could output the file with the same name with an extra extension?

Comment: @Nick Are you looking for this, I am not sure: `write.table( x_in, paste0("path/",quote(x_in),".csv"))`

Comment: @PKumar, kinda. So in the files folder there are files that are like "CRG01_002", CRG01_046, etc. I'd like the new files in the new foldder to be like "CRG_046_good"